# How should we use time reversal operator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conventions, definition, time-reversal-symmetry

In Peskin & Schroeder's QFT textbook, section 3.6. [Time reversal operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry) on a operator, for example, Dirac field $\psi(t,x)$, is 
$$
T\psi(t,x)T
$$
Some other textbooks, mostly, like QFT written by Srednicki (Section 40), time reversal is 
$$
T^{-1}\psi(t,x)T
$$
This looks more "mathematically", because this is how we make isomorphism for a group. However, due to $T^2=-1$ (for Fermions), these two operations are differed by $-1$.

So, what's the problem of Peskin & Schroeder's QFT?